# How to prevent my lamp shining through materials

Tags: game-engine

I have 2 Walls and a lamp in between them. The walls stays close to the floor, there is nothing between but the light is shinning through which is completely nonsense. How to prevent this behavior?

[image]

Comment: It probably won't look very good, and if you start doing it to all your lamps there will be a performance hit - but you can try giving each lamp a shadow. The spectacular on your ground plane still might look wierd behind the wall, but at least there will be no direct light shining on it.

Comment: Thank you, i tried that right now. But if i do that (hopefully i did it right) it looks like there is no specularity at all, so wouldnt it be better to turn off specularity in this case?

Comment: My solution is to either lay a duplicate ground (plane) a little above the original and either break it in 2 or trim or shape it's adjoining edge where the ight is leaking through.  Place that duplicate in a separate layer and set the lamp(s) to "This Layer Only",   Duplicate the main lamp from the 1st layer into the 2nd so the ambient lighting is identical.  I'll drop a short video up on Dropbox.  It's too large for here when GIF'd.  Note - almost all of my rendering is in OpenGL and that can sometimes appear different to Blender Render and certainly will with Cycles.